# What do I put in my package.json file to get "yarn start" to work?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am currently following a tutorial on how to setup and use toastify, and I have followed the tutorial up to the point where the person in the tutorial inputs `yarn start` into the terminal, and his code output opens in his browser. but when I do it the terminal outputs this: `yarn run v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.` and nothing happens. I followed the tutorial exactly and the person in the tutorial does not do anything with packag.json and his code still works. Why isn't my code working? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a start script defined in your package.json

Ex:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "You should write your start script here"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is a start script? and could you show me how to connect a start script to my javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

`npm run start` with the definition at the package.json like this:

`"start": "react-scripts start",`

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same situation before，
Maybe you'd better check that you're running the command in the right directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should write ‘start’ in package.json

if you have a react-native app,

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-native start"
}
```